# Asignar valor a una columna en c#

Tags: c#

mi intención es buscar la columna 11 de mi archivo .csv y dependiendo del string que realize unas cosas u otras. Suelen ser 4 tipos diferentes como pongo en el código por lo tanto si reconoce en un archivo que empieza por F que vaya al if que contenga la f por ejemplo si contiene RECC pues que vaya al if de RECC. Pero al ser booleano no me aclaro como formular esto yo he intentado hacer eso pero no me funciona, alguna propuesta? Gracias de antemano.

Código:

```
  string root = "C:\\test\\csv\\PR";
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(root);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(root);
      //  string valor = "";
      
                    foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*.csv"))
                    {
                        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(fi.FullName)) // pasamos el path del fichero csv
                        {
                            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                            parser.SetDelimiters(";"); // delimitador de csv
                            while (!parser.EndOfData)
                            {
                                //Processing row
                                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                              
                                    foreach (var i in fields[11]){
                                   
                                    var recc = fields[11].StartsWith("RECC");
                                    var recp = fields[11].StartsWith("RECP");
                                    var f = fields[11].StartsWith("F");
                                    var c = fields[11].StartsWith("C");

                                    if (i == recc) {
                                    DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                                    linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                                    linea.fechaAsiento = fields[1];
                                    } else if (i == recp){
                                    DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                                    linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                                    linea.fechaAsiento = fields[1];
                                    }else if (i == f){
                                    DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                                    linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                                    linea.fechaAsiento = fields[1];
                                    }else if (i == c){ 
                                     DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                                    linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                                    linea.fechaAsiento = fields[1];
                                    }else{
                                     DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                                    linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                                    linea.fechaAsiento = fields[1];
                                    }
                                }
                               
                                if (hashDiccionari.ContainsKey(linea.documento) == false)
                                {
                                    List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = new List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC>();
                                    lista.Add(linea);
                                    hashDiccionari.Add(linea.documento, lista);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = hashDiccionari[linea.documento];
                                    lista.Add(linea);
                                }
                            }
                        }// fin

        }

        LoopAndWritteAC(hashDiccionari);

    }
```

Comment: no es mejor usar un switch en vez los if?

Comment: si pero el problema es que no sé como buscar bien por string

Comment: ¿Por qué comparas i con recc, recp ,f y c? en lugar de solo hacer if(recc){ ... }?

Comment: Porque dependiendo del valor que coja en fields[11] quiero que entre a un sitio alomejor me equivoque haciendolo

Comment: ¿Los archivos son  grandes?¿Cuántos registros tiene cada archivo en promedio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vas por buen camino, sólo que la parte donde sacas tantas variables para comparar, podrías cambiarlo por una estructura de esta manera:

```
switch (i)
{
    case "RECC":
        break;
    case "RECP":
        break;
    case "F":
        break;
    case "C":
        break;
}
```

`i` ya tiene el valor que estás utilizando, así que podemos preguntar directamente si `i` es igual a cada uno de tus valores buscados, y, dependiendo el caso, hacer algo.

Espero la respuesta te sirva. ¡Saludos!